# Java 8: Get default value from HashMap and update underlying map

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8

I'm looking for the best way (readability and efficiency) of providing a default value for a `HashMap` get operation but to also have the underlying map updated with that default value if a value is not already present.

I understand there are 3rd party libraries out there, but I'd prefer to stick with standard Java. Here are some different ways I've thought of:

**Old school**

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> someIntegerListLookup = new HashMap<>();
String key = "key";
...
List<Integer> integerList = someIntegerListLookup.get(key);

if (integerList == null) {
    integerList = new ArrayList<>();
    someIntegerListLookup.put(key, integerList);
}
```

**Java 8 Map methods**

```
// getOrDefault
List<Integer> integerList = someIntegerListLookup.getOrDefault(key, new ArrayList<>());
someIntegerListLookup.put(key, integerList);

// putIfAbsent
someIntegerListLookup.putIfAbsent(key, new ArrayList<>());
List<Integer> integerList = someIntegerListLookup.get(key);
```

**Using Java 8 Optionals**

```
List<Integer> integerList = 
    Optional.ofNullable(someIntegerListLookup.putIfAbsent(key, new ArrayList<>()))
    .orElse(someIntegerListLookup.get(key));
```

Not a fan of this approach from a readability point of view.

Using an 'or else' supplier:

```
List<Integer> integerList = Optional.ofNullable(someIntegerListLookup.get(key))
    .orElseGet(() -> {
        // Only runs if the map contains no value for the key
        List<Integer> defaultIntegersList = new ArrayList<>();
        someIntegerListLookup.put(key, defaultIntegersList);
        return defaultIntegersList;
    });
```

Right now I'm leaning towards the above solution being the best option. Are there other (better) solutions out there for this that I haven't thought of or come across?

Comment: You're looking for `computeIfAbsent()`.

Comment: Thanks @shmosel. Nice and simple, that's exactly what I needed. I'm still trying to get familiar with all the Java 8 apis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method is designed for exactly this purpose:

```
List<Integer> value = 
    someIntegerListLookup.computeIfAbsent("a", x -> new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: As you can see in [answer by Eran](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41375969/5221149), you can use a method reference instead of the lambda expression.

Comment: @Andreas This is wrong. The mapping function parameter takes the key as an argument. Since `ArrayList` doesn't have a constructor from `String`, using `ArrayList::new` isn't appropriate here. You have to use a lambda, or something equivilant.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to create a new `ArrayList` unnecessarily if the key is present.

Therefore use :

```
List<Integer> integerList = someIntegerListLookup.computeIfAbsent(key, s -> new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: The second example doesn't compile. See the discussion I'm having with Andreas on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41375974/2422776).

Comment: There's a fundamental difference between `putIfAbsent()` and `computeIfAbsent()`: the former returns null in the absent case, which isn't what OP wants. Also, `ArrayList::new` wont compile unless `key` is `Integer`, in which case you'd be better off if it didn't compile.

Comment: @Mureinik My bad, I didn't read the signature of that method carefully. Will fix.

Comment: @shmosel I missed that. Thanks for the comment.